# Scan screen for color and replicate steps with autoit

Tags: automation, autoit

i have a game with 4 buttons on screen,
i need to replicate the click on the buttons,
there is some sequence on the screen, the computer start with 1 click on each click i need to replicate the click...
after 1 click it increase to 2 clicks 3 clicks and etc...
i started with this code but i'm relay stuck... can any one give me any direction for continue?

```
    HotKeySet("{F1}", loco)
#include <Array.au3>
Global $Coords
Global $Array[0]
Local $Green = 0xFDEA68 ;Clicked 
Local $Gray = 0xF5F2F0;Clicked 
Local $RED = 0xD12321A;Clicked 
Local $Blue = 0x55ECD1;Clicked 
Local $BackGreen = 0xE1183C;Click released
Local $BackGray = 0xF0F4F9;Click released
Local $BackRed = 0x21968F;Click released
Local $BackBlue = 0x66212C;Click released


While 1
   Do
      $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $Green)
       If Not(@Error) Then
          Sleep(100)
          While 1
             $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $BackGreen)
             If Not(@Error) Then
               _ArrayAdd($Array,"Green")
               ExitLoop
            EndIf
         WEnd
      EndIf

      $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $Gray)
      If Not(@Error) Then
          Sleep(100)
          While 1
          $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $BackGray)
          If Not(@Error) Then
            _ArrayAdd($Array,"Gray")
            ExitLoop
         EndIf
         WEnd
      EndIf

      $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $RED)
      If Not(@Error) Then
                  Sleep(100)
               While 1
          $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $BackRed)
          If Not(@Error) Then
            _ArrayAdd($Array,"Red")
            ExitLoop
         EndIf
         WEnd
      EndIf
      $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $Blue)
      If Not(@Error) Then

          Sleep(100)
          While 1
          $Coords = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth - 1, @DesktopHeight - 1, $BackBlue)
          If Not(@Error) Then
            _ArrayAdd($Array,"Blue")
            ExitLoop
         EndIf
         WEnd
      EndIf
      Sleep(1000)
   Until StringLen($Coords) > 0
   Local $ArrLen = UBound($Array)
   For $i = 0 To $ArrLen - 1
      ConsoleWrite("Color: " & $Array[$i] & @CRLF)
   Next
         ;_ArrayDelete($Array,0:)

    ;  MouseClick("Left",$Coords[0],$Coords[1],1,5)


    Sleep(1000)
 WEnd


Func loco()
Exit 12
EndFunc
```

Comment: consider we can't replicate your issue, because we don't have that game. So you have to include all info we need to help you. Especially: **What** doesn't work? And **how** does it not work (desired result vs. actual result). A lot of code that we can't run isn't helpful.

Comment: If there are four buttons (assuming their position is fix), searching for pixels all over the screen seems highly ineffective. Consider `PixelGetColor`, maybe even `Switch PixelGetColor($x1,$x2)`